# Using Scala and reflection to list an array of classes in a package

Tags: scala, reflection

**Please note:** This question is about how to accomplish classpath scanning (via reflection) in **Scala**, not Java. I don't see that question anywhere on this site, and so I don't believe this is a duplicate question.

---

I have Scala a project directory structure that looks like this:

```
myapp/
  src/main/scala/
    com/
      me/
        myapp/
          messages/
            BaseMessage.scala
            FizzMessage.scala
          utils
            <omitted for brevity>
          logging
            <omitted for brevity>
          driver
            <omitted for brevity>
```

Notice the `messages` package. Currently it only has two classes defined inside of it, `BaseMessage` (an abstract base class) and `FizzMessage` (extends `BaseMessage`). But eventually it will contain hundreds of other classes that are all `BaseMessage` subclasses.

In my code I have the following:

```
deviceManager.registerMessage(new FizzMessage())
```

As I add dozens, possibly hundreds of `BaseMessage` subclasses to that `messages` package over time, I would have to add a line of code to "register" each new message type. Subsequently, if I refactor or remove messages I will have to remember to remove their respective line of registration code from above. This will be a pain to manage and I'm wondering if I could just use reflection to scan the `messages` package for `BaseMessage` impls, and then subsequently register them:

```
val messageImpls : Array[T > BaseMessage] = getViaReflection("com.me.myapp.messages")
messageImpls.foreach { msgImpl =>
  deviceManager.registerMessage(msgImpl)
}
```

Any ideas as to how I could accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you find all classes in a package using reflection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection)

Comment: Thanks @Jasper-M (+1) I know how to do this in java, my question is more about whether Scala offers any syntactic sugar/APIs here.

Comment: @smeeb does `classLoader` of Scala's [getClass](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-determine-class-of-scala-object-getclass-method/) offer enough syntactic sugar for you?

Answer (score -1):

If you're able to access the classes of interest using `getResources` then you can filter through those results, even recursing children directories (not shown here):

```scala
def getClasses(packageName: String) = {
    val classLoader = getClass.getClassLoader
    val path = packageName.replace('.', '/')
    val resources: util.Enumeration[URL] = classLoader.getResources(path)

    Iterator.continually((resources, resources.nextElement))
      .takeWhile(_._1.hasMoreElements)
      .map{ case (_, resource: URL) =>
        new File(resource.getFile)
          .listFiles
          .withFilter(_.getName.endsWith(".class"))
          .map{ file =>
            Class.forName(packageName + '.' + file.getName.dropRight(6))
          }
      }
  }
```